# Ubuntu doesn't see the free space after resizing partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

So I just used the GParted tool to resize my Ubuntu partition to extend it to the left to gain some 80GB extra, apparently ubuntu recognizes it but at the same time it doesn't, here's what I mean:

[image: Devices & Locations Window]

But when I click on the drive itself it only sees the folders coming out of the previous partition (around 16GB):

Disk Usage Analyser in current Partition:

[image]

Now I wouldn't mind if that only meant I could not see my disk usage laid out in a nice circular infogram, but I can't download/install things because Ubuntu says that the disk is already full:

steam can't update:

[image]

Note for some reason I am able to install from the Ubuntu software aplication.

Comment: A screenshot of Gparted may be useful.

Comment: Did you click the**Apply** button in gparted after resizing?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like resize2fs did not get run after your partition was resized.  Some partition tools do that automatically, some dont.  Run in a terminal:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda?
```

Using the sda partition number for "?".
The default is to fill the partition, and may be done on a mounted filesystem.  Neverthless, back-up anything important first, these sort of operations can go badly wrong.

Comment: I get "Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda1", even when booting into a rescue usb stick